# How to call class method in Django URLs path?

Tags: python, django, django-views

How to call class method in Django URLs path?

I want to call `data_display` method inside `DataLoad` class. how can i call it in my URLs.py file? so when i hit the path then it will render to the `data_display.html` template.

`views.py`

```
class DataLoad:
    
    def __init__(self, save_path, name_of_file):
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.name_of_file = name_of_file
    def file_load(self):
        file_path = os.path.join(self.save_path, self.name_of_file+".html")
        return file_path
    def data_display(request,*args, **kwargs):
        df = pd.read_csv("/home/satyajit/Desktop/opensource/data/us_amz.csv", low_memory=False)
        json_records = df.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
        data = []
        data = json.loads(json_records)
        context = {'data': data}
        return render(request, "home/data_display.html", context)
```

`urls.py`

```
from apps.home.views import DataLoad
data = DataLoad.data_display(request)

urlpatterns = [
    #path('data_display', DataLoad.as_view(), name='data_display'),
    path('data_display', data, name='data_display'),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/), your view must extends the `View` class and your method should be name as the HTTP method you want to match.

```py
from django.views import View

class DataLoad(View):
    def get(request, **kwargs):
        df = pd.read_csv("/home/satyajit/Desktop/opensource/data/us_amz.csv", low_memory=False)
        # ...
        return render(request, "home/data_display.html", context)

# url.py
from apps.home.views import DataLoad

urlpatterns = [
    path('data_display', DataLoad.as_view(), name='data_display'),
]
```

### Dependency injection

This part answer the OP comment.

If you want to have a better decoupling of you DataLoad from the request, you will need to split your view from your `Dataload` classes.
This is called dependency injection.

So you have your `DataLoad` classes that don't use any HTTP related things:

```py
# file: core/dataload.py

class DataLoad:
    def __init__(self, save_path, name_of_file):
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.name_of_file = name_of_file

    def file_load(self):
        file_path = os.path.join(self.save_path, self.name_of_file+".html")
        return file_path

    def data_display():
        df = pd.read_csv("...us_amz.csv", low_memory=False)
        json_records = df.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
        return json.loads(json_records)
```

You then build a view that will use this class.
Your View *depends* on `DataLoad`.
You *inject* a `DataLoad` instance into your view.
Your `DataLoad` class is *decoupled* from your view.

```py
# file: views.py

class DisplayDataView(View):
    data_load_service = None

    def __init__(self, data_load_service):
        self.data_load_service = data_load_service

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'home/data_display.html', {
            'data': this.data_load_service.data_display(),
        }
```

You then build your url passing a `DataLoad` instance to your view

```py
# file: urls.py

from core.dataload import DataLoad

data_load_service = DataLoad(...)

urls = [
    path(
        'data-load',
        DisplayDataView.as_view(
            data_load_service=data_load_service,
        ),
        name='data-load',
    ),
]
```

This is the basic idea. I would personaly find another place for the `DataLoad` instanciation but it should do the trick for you until you find out a better way to organize all this.

Main point here is *decoupling* what your business logic is from the HTTP part (ie: request/response) of your application.

Comment: I want to call it as OOPs method. so how can i do that with OOPs method?

Comment: @SatyajitBarik I just added some info about what you call *OOP method* to my response. I hope it helps.